# Database Project - how can I access SQLCMD Variables in the Post build event command line

Tags: sqlcmd, sql-server-data-tools, database-project, post-build-event

I've got a database project that I'm wanting to have call a batch file in the post-build event.  So far that's pretty simple, but I want to be able to set some variables in the SQLCMD Variables section of the project, then pass those variables as arguments to the batch file.

When I reference any of my user-defined SQLCMD variables in my post-build event, they're just empty strings.

As an example, if I create a SQLCMD variable called $(MyVariable) and give it a default value of ABC, I try referencing it when calling my batch file with :

```
call <path and name of batch file> $(MyVariable)
```

and the parameter is empty.

Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: If you add your variable to "SQLCMD Variables" in your Project Properties they should be available. How are you supplying the value?

Comment: I've added the variables to "SQLCMD Variables" in my Project Properties, and I've tried setting a value in the Default which doesn't work, and when I use the Local value, it will only save for me as a user, not for anyone else who checks out the project.  Additionally, I could only get access the local variable not by it's name, but by something like $(SQLcmdVar__1).